# FFMPEG showaves with both color and colorkey

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm actually using this shell code to generate a video with black waveforms over a background image with FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -y -i $local_mp3 -loop 1 -i $local_image -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -level 4.0 -acodec aac -strict -2 -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

I just looking how to give a different color to the waveforms. I tried a lot and I'm still stuck after decades :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i $local_mp3 -loop 1 -i $local_image -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:colors=black,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -level 4.0 -acodec aac -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

See the docs for the showwaves filter: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves

Comment: Tried but.. ```[Parsed_showwaves_0 @ 0x258f620] Option 'colors' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2590e60] Error initializing filter 'showwaves' with args 's=1280x720:mode=line:colors=black'```

Comment: You appear to have an old version of ffmpeg. `colors` was added in Jan 2016. Upgrade.

Comment: You save me a week, I'll send you a beer cluster wherever you want :) I actually upgrade ffmpeg to the 3.4.2-1~16.04.york0.2 version using jonathonf repo under Ubuntu 16: `add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3 && apt update && apt install ffmpeg`